# Horror Novel about gigantic mansion

Tags: story-identification, novel, horror

I looked at a paperback copy of this novel in a supermarket in about the 1980s.

The title may have been *The Lodge*, or something similar.  There may have been a group of supernatural investigators investigating a gigantic haunted mansion, as in *The Haunting of Hill House* or in *Rose Red*.

I remember a line to the effect that they were penetrating deeper into the house, which gave the impression that it was an incredibly vast building.

Comment: Are you sure you saw it in the 1980's?

Comment: There was a Doctor Who episode called _The Lodger_, where the house he stayed in had more storeys accessible from the inside than it had on the outside.

Comment: There's _The Lodge_ by Colleen Mahan. I don't know if the story fits.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly Mark Z. Danielewski's [*House of Leaves.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Leaves)

From the Publishers Weekly review on the Amazon page:

> Zampano, a blind Angelino recluse, dies, leaving behind
>   the notes to a manuscript that's an account of a film called The
>   Navidson Report. In the Report, Pulitzer Prize-winning news
>   photographer Will Navidson and his girlfriend move with their two
>   children to a house in an unnamed Virginia town in an attempt to save
>   their relationship. One day, Will discovers that the interior of the
>   house measures more than its exterior. More ominously, a closet
>   appears, then a hallway. Will contacts a number
>   of people, including explorer Holloway Roberts, who mounts an
>   expedition with his two-man crew. They discover a vast stairway and
>   countless halls. The whole structure occasionally groans, and the
>   space reconfigures, driving Holloway into a murderous frenzy. The
>   story of the house is stitched together from disparate accounts, until
>   the experience becomes somewhat like stumbling into Borges's Library
>   of Babel.

Comment: Hi Joe. I've updated your link - it was pointing to an unrelated Star Trek site.

Comment: @John Rennie: That's odd. Thanks!

Comment: House of Leaves was published in 2000 which should be about 10 or 20 years after I remember looking though the book in question.